# Why does a script named "GameManager" have a ⚙️ icon instead of a #️⃣ icon in the project assets?

Tags: unity, c#

I am learning to use Unity for game development and one of the scripts in the Unity project window has a weird icon vs the other scripts. I'm not sure if it's something I should be concerned about or not. Does anyone know why this occurred?

[image: Screenshot showing the one script with a different icon]

Comment: Because of its name. Probably some leftover from earliest versions of Unity where the name was associated with some special kind of asset. I don't think it matters anymore but don't quote me on it.

Comment: Nice proper use of emojis in the title

Comment: I'm not sure how well it is search optimized, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As another user said in the comment, this is a bug left over from an older version, and the official unity team decided not to fix it.

[This is the report](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/giving-a-monobehaviour-script-particular-names-changes-its-icon):

> The Icon for a MonoBehaviour script in the Project view can change if it is given particular names. Two examples are 'Folder' and 'GameManager', but there are almost certainly others.

> RESOLUTION NOTE (2019.2.X):
> Due to low severity, we decided not to change this behaviour.

This situation also occurs with other keywords, for example, if you name a script as `Folder`, its icon will become the icon of the folder. It has no effect on the correctness of the program. You can put your `GameManager` class under a custom namespace to solve the display problem.

And, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965981/special-icon-when-naming-a-monobehaviour-class-gamemanager) shows how to find all keywords with a special icon.